# NuGet packages: Do we need to add them to both referencing and referenced projects?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

This may sound trivial, but I'm still trying to understand what's going on here.

My VSTO add-in contains the following projects (VS2022, .NET Framework 4.8):

1. Addin (VSTO add-in, references #2)
2. View (WPF control library, references #3)
3. VM (Class library, references #4)
4. DataAccess (Class library, references RestSharp nuget package)

When I build the project, #4 copies its DLL as well as RestSharp DLL to its output folder. Thereupon #3 copies its own DLL as well as the two DLLs coming from #4 to its output. But #2 does not copy RestSharp DLL to its output, only View, VM and DataAccess DLLs. #1 also follows the suite and ignores RestSharp DLL.

Why? Has this got anything to do with the fact that Data Access is targeting .NET Standard 2.0, unlike other layers which are targeting .NET Framework 4.8?

I have fixed the problem by adding RestSharp's NuGet reference to project #2 as well, but it feels like a hack to me. I'm just trying to understand how Visual Studio or MSBuild decides whether or not to include dependencies of referenced projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147430/visual-studio-projects-copy-dependencies-from-referenced-project-into-output).

I think you were right here:

> Why? Has this got anything to do with the fact that Data Access is targeting .NET Standard 2.0, unlike other layers which are targeting .NET Framework 4.8?

For now I will be implementing your hack solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32504447)